# Generate Every Random Number in a Range

Tags: java, random, range

I want to get EVERY random number within a certain range exactly once.

For example, if the range was 1-10, I would want every number 1-10 in a random order.  What is a simple, fast, and clean algorithm for doing this?

Is there some existing way to do this automatically in Java?

Comment: Generate a list of numbers from 1-10, then shuffle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Populate a list containing number from 1-10 and then use `Collections.shuffle(list);`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way from the JDK, but the simplest approach is to use `Collections.shuffle()` on a list of all the numbers in the range:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

then return the contents of list in order